# Eigenvalues of the ODE: $y''+x^2y = \lambda y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of  $y''+x^2y = \lambda y$. Basically how I can solve this equation to use the eigenvalues?

I don't want a full solution only hint, please!

Comment: It's a harmonic oscillator (Schrodinger) equation. The solutions are Hermite polynomials multiplied by a Gaussian function. Quantum mechanics textbooks all contain the solution to this problem

Comment: Yes you are right. Can you recommend some books in Quantum mechanics including this equation?

Comment: Any book. If you Google Harmonic Oscillator Quantum Mechanics, you will find dozens of resources with full solutions in different ways. I can only think of Russian ones myself, cause I learned from them

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answers..